# Why isn't atmega8 using the internal oscillator at 8MHz by default?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega

I've been using the `atmega8` for some time and encountered a problem related to timers that require higher clock speeds. I missed the part in the datasheet and thought that the default clock speed of `1MHz` is the maximum internal frequency I can get. However, it is quite trivial to fuse the bits and get frequency of `8MHz` or even overclock.

What are the drawbacks of using `8MHz` clock speed by default?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241575/atmega-why-is-the-prescaler-factory-defaulted-to-8

Comment: Because the internal oscillator is very unpredictable, its frequency depends on supply voltage, temperature, aging, phase of the moon etc. You can program the chip to use that internal oscillator by default though. It is more common to use an external crystal to make the clock. Crystals are much, much better at keeping to the same frequency. Then if you program the chip to wait for one minute, it will actually wait for one minute and not 50 or 80 seconds depending on whatever.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie whooops, it's midnight + full moon now. Should expect minutes to be a bit longer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have higher power consumption. As you say: If you need it, configure it at startup to 8MHz